# Java Nested MouseListener

Tags: java, swing

So I have a JPanel which has a mouseListener.

```
public class X extends JPanel
{
    public X() {
        add(new Y());
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("X Triggered");
            }
        });
    }
}

public class Y extends JComponent
{
    public Y() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Y Triggered");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If I do not add the MouseListener in Y, the click event in X works fine. If I do add the MouseListener in Y, the MouseListener in X stops responding to clicks. What is wrong with my MouseListener?

Comment: Consider the solution `ParentPanel.this.processMouseEvent(e)` highlighted in the non accepted answer, not the one proposed into the accepted duplicate answer.

Comment: @Jack Is there a way without making an inner class?

Comment: @Jack Does MouseAdapter also override MouseMotionListener?

Comment: No, you've got `MouseMotionAdapter` for that.